# how to convert HTML page to PDF using ITEXT or PDFCROWD API

Tags: itext

PDF created will be based on dynamic HTML page.

Using ITEXT 5 or 7 with XMLWORKERHELPERCLASS would be lengthy process.

If i am using pdfcrowd API it seems to be ok but not able to generate on localhost or any other private ip. I am ready to pay for their services if they achieve above issue.

Comment: What exactly do you want to say? It appears as if you want a pdfcrowd solution, on the other hand you tag your question itext.

Comment: Indeed, the question reveals a lack of respect because iText 7 doesn't have an `XmlWorkerHelper` class (that's iText 5 terminology). Hence the allegation that using iText 7 and the pdfHtml add-on would be a lengthy process is false. The OP probably mentions iText because the iText brand is so strong, but that is hardly an excuse to use that tag. I voted to close the question as "unclear" because there is no code sample that allows people to reproduce the problem. It is unclear which iText problem the OP is facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get iText 7 (the core library) and the pdfHtml add-on (the part that will parse the HTML+CSS and convert it to iText objects). Go to [github](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/tag/7.0.2) to find out how to download these.

Suppose that you have this [HTML](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/BlogpostHTML.txt):

[image]

With this corresponding [CSS](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/BlogpostCss.txt):

[image]

Then you can use this code snippet:

```
ConverterProperties converterProperties =
    new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(resoureLocation);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
    new FileInputStream(HTMLSource),
    new FileOutputStream(pdfDestination), converterProperties);
```

Where `resourceLocation` points at your base URI, `HTMLSource` is the path to your HTML file, and `pdfDestination` is the path where you want the resulting PDF to be written.

When you execute this code, you will get the following [PDF](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Blogpost.pdf):

[image]

Note that buying a commercial license may be necessary if you intend to use iText in the context of a proprietary software project.

Comment: Sir i am extremely srry.... Its a proud moment that Sir Bruno answered my querry . I am a Software Engineer with 4 months of experience,  I tried my best by reading your Itext developers forum and generated pdf too but now the requirement was as such that I was little confused and that too very priority. Sir much more need to say, I will contact you via sales.isc@itextpdf.com

Comment: @mkl for tagging pdfCrowd a popup was given by statckoverflow stating that for tagging pdfCrowd Api i need some reputation. I felt very lucky and  proud about ITEXT

Comment: Couldn't find the `pdfHtml` source code on GitHub, is it coming? The reason I ask is because pretty much every [X]HTML to PDF question I've answered here at SO is _directly_ attributable to having source code available to learn from....

Comment: @kuujinbo The source code isn't available yet because some people within iText Group wanted to keep it closed source. Given the amount of people downvoting answers about [iTextSharp license](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384410/1622493) (28 - 29 = -1) and the [AGPL](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5005/27), I had a really hard time convincing those people to open up the source code. The numbers of use in India, e.g. by companies who try to get free consultancy, and then don't pay (e.g. Cognizant) are not helping. Nevertheless, I hope that the pdfHtml source code will be opened.

Comment: @kuujinbo I really don't understand it: some people *love* iText, but *hate* me (and even find it necessary to send me hate mail). They don't understand that I am really trying to keep iText open source, but at the same time need to make sure that we make money.

Comment: No worries - as you know I've used iText for a pretty long time, so I know about the history about why you chose to change the license. As the creator of iText it's **your** decision what direction this goes, nothing else really matters. With that said, I really hope the add on goes open source, otherwise a **LOT** of developers _may_ have no choice but to stick with the 5 branch...

Comment: Not to mention that opening the source code gives developers like me (and @mkl, Chris Haas, etc) who contribute here at SO and on the web on their own "_**Free as in Beer**_" time can _**continue**_ to contribute. :)

Comment: @kuujinbo You don't have to convince me. I have to convince others. Fortunately, I can be very convincing ;-) The decision to make htmlPdf was made, so we'll open up the source code, but it will take a little while.

Comment: @Bruno sir , i am getting com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKeyException: License file for product not loaded.

Comment: @TejasGowda You need to mail sales to get a trial license key.